# How to Combine / Cascade two `3 x 3` Filters into One `5 x 5` Filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, computer-vision, convolution

If you have a uniform 3x3 box filter T which is:

1 1 1

1 1 1

1 1 1

And an 3x3 laplacian filter W which is:

1 -2 1

-2 4 -2

1 -2 1

Can these 2 filters be combined into one 5x5 filter, the order being first T and then W ? (The combination should be possible) And what is the math behind this combination. I can make a 5x5 filter of all one's and after that stride the W filter over that 5x5 and add everything up, is it that simple?

Comment: To cascade two filters, you convolve their coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a convolution kernel $ f $ and another convolution kernel $ g $.
We also have an input signal (1D or 2D) $ x $ and we are after the result of the cascaded convolution:

$$ y = g \ast \left( f \ast x \right) $$

The nice thing about [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is its associativity property.
Which means:

$$ y = g \ast \left( f \ast x \right) = \left( g \ast f \right) \ast x = h \ast x $$

So the equivalent is $ h = g \ast f $ which with the commutative property of convolution means:

$$ h = g \ast f = f \ast g $$

Pay attention that for the discrete case only the Full Convolution (In MATLAB formulation) is commutative.

So in the above:

```
mF = [1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1];
mG = [1, -2, 1; -2, 4, -2; 1, -2, 1];

mH = conv2(mF, mG, 'full')
mH = conv2(mG, mF, 'full')

mH =

     1    -1     0    -1     1
    -1     1     0     1    -1
     0     0     0     0     0
    -1     1     0     1    -1
     1    -1     0    -1     1


mH =

     1    -1     0    -1     1
    -1     1     0     1    -1
     0     0     0     0     0
    -1     1     0     1    -1
     1    -1     0    -1     1
```